# Execution MS SQL Server stored procedure with datetime parameter from Access 2003

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I'm calling a stored procedure with a parameter of a datetime type from ADP Access 2003 and I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the structure '-'

I tried different date formats, but the error is repeated the same type with other structures.

Exec from VBA

```
Me.items.Form.RecordSource = "exec usp_pct_ItemForTree " & cur & "," & usl & ",-1,1,'" & Nz(fltr, "") & "'" & "," & Abs(Nz(inet, 0)) & "," & idb & "," & DueDate
```

After concatenations it looks

```
"exec usp_pct_ItemForTree 0,6,-1,1,'',0,5425157,2015-09-22"
```

Stored procedure

```
alter procedure [dbo].[usp_pct_ItemForTree]
    @group_id int = 21, 
    @instoreonly int = 1,
    @idbrand int = -1,
    @hotim bit = 1,
    @fltr varchar(150) = '',
    @inet bit = 0,
    @idbill int = null,
    @dueDate datetime = null
```

Comment: Can you show us what the value of `.RecordSource` looks like after all the concatenations?

Comment: Value of `.RecordSource` is unknown because error `Incorrect syntax` I get before it assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gustav, I'm find solution. It simply was needs to set varchar type of parameter. Not date or datetime.

```
alter procedure [dbo].[usp_pct_ItemForTree]
@group_id int = 21, 
@instoreonly int = 1,
@idbrand int = -1,
@hotim bit = 1,
@fltr varchar(150) = '',
@inet bit = 0,
@idbill int = null,
@dueDate varchar(10) = ''
```

And quotes

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you miss the quotes to wrap date/time expressions in T-SQL:

```
Me.items.Form.RecordSource = "exec usp_pct_ItemForTree " & cur & "," & usl & ",-1,1,'" & Nz(fltr, "") & "'" & "," & Abs(Nz(inet, 0)) & "," & idb & ",'" & DueDate & "'"
```

using Format for T-SQL:

```
Me.items.Form.RecordSource = "exec usp_pct_ItemForTree " & cur & "," & usl & ",-1,1,'" & Nz(fltr, "") & "'" & "," & Abs(Nz(inet, 0)) & "," & idb & ",'" & Format(DueDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
```

using Format for Access:

```
Me.items.Form.RecordSource = "exec usp_pct_ItemForTree " & cur & "," & usl & ",-1,1,'" & Nz(fltr, "") & "'" & "," & Abs(Nz(inet, 0)) & "," & idb & ",#" & Format(DueDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"
```

Comment: Then force the format as shown because `2015-09-22` _as is_ will not work as date expressions in T-SQL must be wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: You also may have to prefix with dbo: `"exec dbo.usp_pct_ItemForTree " & cur & ...`.

Comment: If so, my last idea is to apply an Access formatted date expression as showed.

Comment: Could be that your secret SP is buggy.